# in vb6, how do I retrieve a char* parameter from a C dll?

Tags: string, dll, vb6, function-calls

I am calling a C dll from my VB6 application. The dll has a function call signature as follows.

```
void WINAPI geterrstr(char* foo);
```

where foo is a string that has to be returned.

In my VB6 application, I have tried calling my dll by using the following syntax, but it returns an empty string.

```
Declare Sub geterrstr Lib "technopnp.dll" (ByRef lpbuffer As String)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to;

```
Declare Sub geterrstr Lib "technopnp.dll" (ByVal lpbuffer As String)
...
dim buff as string
buff=string$(n, vbnullchar)
geterrstr buff

//read upto 1st vbnullchar
buff = left$(buff, instr(1, buff, vbnullchar) - 1)
if (buff="") then
  //no data
else
  msgbox buff
end if
```

`n` needs to be an appropriate buffer size, too short and it will crash.

Comment: This Declare implies ANSI conversion. If the data is Unicode use ByVal lpbuffer As Long and pass StrPtr(buff) instead.

Comment: Great, it seems that the string passes correctly. Unfortunately, there is a null terminator in the original C dll, and it is trailed by several square character. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: They are the null characters that were allocated in the VB buffer string & not overwritten by the dll, updated example above with how to strip them.