# How can I retrieve a char* parameter from a C DLL file, by using VB6

Tags: string, api, dll, vb6, function-call

In my project I have to decode chips,  Decoding was done first with a C ++ compiler and a DLL fil. Fortunately the validation of the decoding with C++ is done and working.

the imported C dll functions are as follows:

```
short int  Byte_read(BOOL Mode,int cm, char* tet, char* stat, char* adr, char* nbr, char* data);
```

But unfortunately my test decoding with VB6 and the same DLL file does not work. I've done several tests and still I can not read the chip. I need to be able to decode with VB6 and cannot understand where the fault is or if I'm missing any instructions on how to achieve this?

The VB6 code that is non-functional is as follows:

```
Const DATA_ARRAY = 129

Private Sub Command2_Click() 


Dim x As Long
Dim CData(DATA_ARRAY) As Byte 
Dim buffer(3) As Byte 

x= lire(True, 1, "2", buffer, "00", "09", CData)
```

Please check with me if code is correct or not
thank you for helping me and render me service is important for me.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you do not have a hardware problem?

Comment: Yes, no hardware problem because I already validated decoding with C and I saw flashing leds.

Answer (score 0):

Some parameters of `Byte_read` are character arrays rather than strings.

There is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106496/in-vb6-how-do-i-retrieve-a-char-parameter-from-a-c-dll) which explains how to access string parameters.

Try as alternative:

```
Private Declare Function Byte_read Lib "RFID_VC_VB1.dll" ( _ 
ByVal Mode As Long, _ 
ByVal nCom As Long, _
ByRef head() As byte, _ 
ByRef status() As byte, _ 
ByRef adresse() As byte, _ 
ByRef number() As byte, _ 
ByRef Data() As byte) As Long
```

You have to map the strings to the byte arrays. Make use of the fact that the last byte is zero.

Comment: error: Type mismatch: array type or defined by the user expected

Answer (score 0):

Your `declare` seems ok. The problem is with the actual parameters declaration. These byte arrays get casted to `Strings` **and** are passed `ByVal` so whatever is returned gets discarded just after the call.

For output string parameters to get any data these must be allocated by the caller like this

```
Dim CData       As String
Dim buffer      As String
...

CData = String$(DATA_ARRAY + 1, 0)
buffer = String$(3 + 1, 0)
retour_byte_read = Byte_read(True, 1, "2", buffer, "00", "09", CData)
CData = Left$(CData, InStr(CData, Chr$(0)) - 1)
buffer = Left$(buffer, InStr(buffer, Chr$(0)) - 1)

Debug.Print CData, buffer
```

Note that it's callers responsibility to allocate enough space for the "worst" case -- this has to by documented in the C function reference.

Also note that `ByVal` strings in VB6 declares are not passed `ByVal` -- this is a hack to mark string parameters as `char*` type (ANSI). VB6 does the unicode -> ANSI conversion before calling the function and backward ANSI -> unicode after function call, so you get a nice "VB string" in your output string parameters.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing as CData and bueffer for "head, number and address" but still no positive result.